# React.js inserting multiple states into one main state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an app where an 'Owner' can have multiple 'cars', I have my App.js file where the Owner enters there name and can enter there car details ('Car name' and 'Car Type'), a Owner can have multiple Cars, and when they click 'Add car entry' a Component where they enter there car details called 'OwnersCars' is repeated. Like so

[image: With one 'OwnersCars' component] to [image: With two 'OwnersCars' component]

If an owner fills out the input boxes in this component (For X amount of cars) then clicks 'Save Owner' i want the owner aswell as a list of all there cars to be saved into one State.

Currently i have my app.js file like this (count is used to know the number of OwnersCars divs)

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import OwnersCars from './ownersCars';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(1) 

  const [OwnerInput, SetOwnerInput] = useState({
    id: "",
    Name: "",
    cars: []

});

const [newCarInput, SetnewCarInput] = useState({
    id: "",
    Type: "",
    CarName: ""
    });


  const removeDiv = () => {
    //console.log('sw\nag')
    setCount(count - 1)
  }

  const repeatDiv = () => {
      //console.log('sw\nag')
      setCount(count + 1)
  }

  const displayCarInput = (e) => {
    //console.log(count, "<--key")
    return ( ([...Array(count)].map((e, i) => <OwnersCars onAddNameCar={addNewCarNameHandler} onAddTypeCar={addNewCarTypeHandler}></OwnersCars> )))
  }

  const displayRemove = (e) =>{
    if (count > 1) {
        return (<button className='removeAnimalButton' onClick={removeDiv}> <dt> Remove Last Animal Entry</dt></button>)
    }
  }

  const NameHandler = (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value)
    SetOwnerInput((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, Name: e.target.value };
      });
  }

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = Math.random().toString()
    const OwnerData = {
        id: value,
        Name: OwnerInput.Name,
        cars: [newCarInput]

    };

    console.log(OwnerData, "<--- ownerdata with cars data");
  }

  const addNewCarNameHandler = (values) => {
    //console.log(values, "<---5")
    SetnewCarInput((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, CarName: values };
      });

  };

  const addNewCarTypeHandler = (values) => {
    //console.log(values, "<---5")
    SetnewCarInput((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, Type: values };
      });

  };



  return (

    <div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
            <button onClick={submitHandler} ><dt>Save Owner</dt></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div className="wrapper">

            <div class="new-owner-div">
                <h5>Owner</h5>
                    <hr/>
                      <form>
                      <div>
                            <input type="name" id="exampleInputClinic" placeholder="Owner Name"  onChange={NameHandler}/>
                      </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="new-owner-div-2">
                <h5>Owners Cars</h5>
                    <hr/>
                        {displayCarInput()}
                        <div>
                            <button onClick={repeatDiv}> <dt> Add Car Entry</dt></button>
                            {displayRemove()}
                        </div>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

and i have my ownersCars.js file with the OwnersCars component like this

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';

function OwnersCars(props) {


    const CarNameHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        props.onAddNameCar(e.target.value)
    }

    const CarTypeHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        props.onAddTypeCar(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Car name</h3>
                        <span></span>
                        <h3>Type</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <input placeholder="Car Name" onChange={CarNameHandler}/>
                        </div>
                        <span class="span1-box"></span>
                        <div class="height">
                            <input class="input-box-OA-2"  placeholder="Car Type" onChange={CarTypeHandler}/>
                        </div>
                        <span class="span1-box"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )

} 

export default OwnersCars
```

but when i click save user it only saves the latest car entry!

Would anyone be able to help?

Sorry for the mess and lack of css i removed a bunch of things from the original code so it was easier to follow on StackOverflow. Also im fairly new to react so im sure theres alot of things that need to be changed for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push to owner cars, every time you add a new car. Please find the code below for App.js changes. check repeatDiv. Similarly, you need to pop from cars the particular car with remove div which I leave it to you

```
    import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import OwnersCars from "./Owner";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const [OwnerInput, SetOwnerInput] = useState({
    id: "",
    Name: "",
    cars: []
  });

  const [newCarInput, SetnewCarInput] = useState({
    id: "",
    Type: "",
    CarName: ""
  });

  const removeDiv = () => {
    //console.log('sw\nag')
    setCount(count - 1);
  };

  const repeatDiv = () => {
    //console.log('sw\nag')
    OwnerInput.cars.push(newCarInput);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const displayCarInput = (e) => {
    //console.log(count, "<--key")
    return [...Array(count)].map((e, i) => (
      <OwnersCars
        onAddNameCar={addNewCarNameHandler}
        onAddTypeCar={addNewCarTypeHandler}
      ></OwnersCars>
    ));
  };

  const displayRemove = (e) => {
    if (count > 1) {
      return (
        <button className="removeAnimalButton" onClick={removeDiv}>
          {" "}
          <dt> Remove Last Animal Entry</dt>
        </button>
      );
    }
  };

  const NameHandler = (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value)
    SetOwnerInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, Name: e.target.value };
    });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = Math.random().toString();
    const OwnerData = {
      id: value,
      Name: OwnerInput.Name,
      cars: OwnerInput.cars
    };

    console.log(OwnerData, "<--- ownerdata with cars data");
  };

  const addNewCarNameHandler = (values) => {
    //console.log(values, "<---5")
    SetnewCarInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, CarName: values };
    });
  };

  const addNewCarTypeHandler = (values) => {
    //console.log(values, "<---5")
    SetnewCarInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, Type: values };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
          <button onClick={submitHandler}>
            <dt>Save Owner</dt>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div class="new-owner-div">
          <h5>Owner</h5>
          <hr />
          <form>
            <div>
              <input
                type="name"
                id="exampleInputClinic"
                placeholder="Owner Name"
                onChange={NameHandler}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="new-owner-div-2">
          <h5>Owners Cars</h5>
          <hr />
          {displayCarInput()}
          <div>
            <button onClick={repeatDiv}>
              {" "}
              <dt> Add Car Entry</dt>
            </button>
            {displayRemove()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And the output with cars saved

[image]

Comment: This is close to what i need, for it to work correctly i should be able to change one of the values from a pervious car and when i click save owner it saves that change. e.g If i write Car2 then change name of Car1 to Car3 then click save owner it should save Car3 not Car1. if that makes sense?

Comment: Yup. Then you might need to rely on id for this. Like if its a new entry have id as empty other wise have the already saved id in a hidden div or something. Coz you need atleast one unique identifier to  distinguish between an update and a new entry. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, im just unsure how to do this, like how can i create an id thats unique and it can remember which div is holding which ID

Comment: @gitmcgee - you can generate the unique ids and maintain just like indexes. Also do give a thumbs up if my solution helped you in someway!